# Route ip via default gw

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing

For a VPN configuration, I need to route a particular public subnet via the tunnel except one of them, because that IP is assigned to the VPN server.

But, because the configuation will fall into multiple particular client setups, I need to avoid define the gateway ip or interface, so I'm looking for the way to add a route to one IP via default gw

```
ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 gw vi default gw
Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "gw" is a garbage.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo route del default
sudo route add default gw 'gw ip'
sudo route add -net 'desired ip' netmask 255.255.255.0 'interface name'
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Can you expand your answer at all to explain what those commands do? Also, note that 'route' is a deprecated command; you should aim to use `ip` from the `iproute2` package instead these days.